# "orca2.db" is not appearing in my windows messenger application

Tags: database, facebook

In my windows 10 the orca2.db which is basically a small backup (cache) of the messenger in our system is not appearing (after i log in with another account) also the fbsyncstore.db is appearing empty but it should not do this.
I have tried to reinstall the messenger application and still facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its completely abstract question didn't make any sense   for what purpose you are using it and what you want to achieve ....

Comment: i am working on facebook recovdery toolkit and i am trying to read messages on my facebook id from my the database messenger application creates in windows by python program, the issue is whenever i log in with some other account the new database for that account is not created. (the database i am using to read the messages it is orca2.db in windows 10 in fb messenger folder for messages and fbsyncstore.db for fb contacts)